# Will Ubuntu (GNOME) 16.10 use GNOME 3.22?

Tags: gnome, 16.10

I can't find it anywhere, not on here, not on Ubuntu news websites, etc. Will 16.10 eventually ship with 3.22?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it will ship with GNOME 3.20 as GNOME 3.22 will be released after the necessary freeze for Ubuntu thus meaning that it will not be able to be shipped in as default.

Although you may upgrade to it on an existing installation with (this will add the necessary semi-unofficial (though maintained by the official Ubuntu GNOME team so it is safe security wise) PPAs and give you the latest version of GNOME available for your version (the next one up)):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

They haven't yet done an article for 16.10, but you can see that this is the case for 16.04: [How To Install GNOME 3.20 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Adding the PPAs will give you a lot of warnings about how it might break your system etc, but I and many others have installed from there and nothing bad has happened. If it was released before the freeze which prevents it being shipped by default you would get the same packages in this PPA so they just say this because it's the latest and could be unstable, but I've never had any problems with it.

Comment: Thanks! I use those PPA's already since 14.04 (currently on 16.04) and I agree that GNOME runs good.

Comment: I believe that 3.22 is now stable, but the staging is a testing ppa.  How do I add a stable ppa to get 3.22?  (i am using gnome 16.04 standard with usual updates)

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti: That's just the wording they give it, it's only just been released so they don't want to call it 'stable'. But I would use it, the latest 'stable' release is in the staging PPA I linked which isn't actually a testing PPA, they just say that. I know it's confusing, but I regularly talk to the Ubuntu GNOME team leaders who maintain the PPA and that's what they tell me.

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti: But you can only upgrade to the next version, so you won't be able to upgrade 3.20 to 3.22 on 16.04, only 3.18 to 3.20. If you want 3.22 you will have to upgrade to 16.10 and upgrade 3.20 there to 3.22.

Comment: uh.. I do not understand your second comment.  So I need to be on 16.10 to do this?  Don't they have any release notes that says how to do this? I read the "release notes" on the gnome web site.. they don't even list a ppa.. just the "features."

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti: You can only upgrade to the next GNOME version through said PPA, if you wish to upgrade to 3.22 using it then you have to be on a system with 3.20 pre-installed as default. So yes, you have to be on 16.10 to get 3.22 from said PPA. I've never known release notes to have anything but notes and features. GNOME just provide the upstream DE, you have to get it from a distributor to have it properly packaged. The PPA I gave will not be listed there because it is a semi-unofficial one run by the Ubuntu GNOME team, it's not an official GNOME PPA, just something nice our team did.

Comment: As pointed out in the article you reference, you should include that if the user doesn't already have GNOME installed he should also install it with `sudo apt install gnome gnome-shell`.

Comment: @Glaedr: The GNOME stack which the asker is referring to is installed by default in the Ubuntu standard flavour as well, one doesn't need to have the full GNOME Desktop Environment installed to reap benefit from the PPA. Plus, installing the GNOME DE through the method you described could actually cause issues in the standard system as Unity is so integrated into it so what you suggest would actually be inadvisable. It would be better to just install Ubuntu GNOME as a fresh install if you want the full DE. If you just want the latest GNOME stack, then doing what I said would do that.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/YakketyYak/Beta1/UbuntuGNOME#Software_Updates), "select" apps will be updated to their GNOME 3.22 versions for Ubuntu (GNOME) 16.10.

Those 3.22 apps will not have changed much from 3.20.

The major components: GNOME Shell, GTK+, the Files app (nautilus), the Settings app (gnome-control-center) all will be 3.20 versions.